# Python re.sub() beginning-of-line anchoring

Tags: python, regex, string, replace

Consider the following multiline string:

```
>> print s
shall i compare thee to a summer's day?
thou art more lovely and more temperate
rough winds do shake the darling buds of may,
and summer's lease hath all too short a date.
```

`re.sub()` replaces all the occurrence of `and` with `AND`:

```
>>> print re.sub("and", "AND", s)
shall i compare thee to a summer's day?
thou art more lovely AND more temperate
rough winds do shake the darling buds of may,
AND summer's lease hath all too short a date.
```

But `re.sub()` doesn't allow `^` anchoring to the beginning of the line, so adding it causes no occurrence of `and` to be replaced:

```
>>> print re.sub("^and", "AND", s)
shall i compare thee to a summer's day?
thou art more lovely and more temperate
rough winds do shake the darling buds of may,
and summer's lease hath all too short a date.
```

How can I use `re.sub()` with start-of-line (`^`) or end-of-line (`$`) anchors?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You forgot to enable multiline mode.

```
re.sub("^and", "AND", s, flags=re.M)
```

> `re.M`
> `re.MULTILINE`
>
> When specified, the pattern character `'^'` matches at the beginning of the string and at the beginning of each line (immediately following each newline); and the pattern character `'$'` matches at the end of the string and at the end of each line (immediately preceding each newline). By default, `'^'` matches only at the beginning of the string, and `'$'` only at the end of the string and immediately before the newline (if any) at the end of the string.

[source](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.M)

The flags argument isn't available for python older than 2.7; so in those cases you can set it directly in the regular expression like so:

```
re.sub("(?m)^and", "AND", s)
```

Answer (score 10):

Add `(?m)` for multiline:

```
print re.sub(r'(?m)^and', 'AND', s)
```

See [the re documentation here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE).